# DevServer 16.1 configuration issues

Tags: easyphp

I'm trying to move from devserver 14 to devserver 16.1 and I am having the following issues.

DevServer 16.1 doesn't start apache, php and mysql automatically. I need to go into the dashboard and manually start each process - after selecting which version to use. Is there an option somewhere to set these default values so that devserver starts them all automatically?

In mysql the datadir reverts back to the default :
`datadir = "C:/myStuff/EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1/eds-binaries/dbserver/mysql5710x160114181656/data/"` and not to where I want it to be `datadir = "C:/myStuff/mySQL_Data/data"`. Why and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's been over 1 week since I posted this question. No responses from anyone not even the easyphp developers. This only shows me that there is no support for this product. Time to look at some other WAMP stacks that are available and do offer real support.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff
- if you haven't already moved to a different dev-server..

I just upgraded EasyPHP from v14 to v16 - its not easy.. ..but::

Once you have selected a version/module for Apache and PHP and started them both.. ..subsequent startups will start these severs automagically.